# Removing 2 Characters From Swift String

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

EDIT: I solved it, I needed to switch two values around. Thank you guys. Now my only question is, I would like to delete everything from the HI to the * (pointer of the class name). **How can I add a range in here to strip everything between HI and & in a String in Swift?**

I generally tend to remove characters from strings in Swift via calls similar to this:

```
textToConvert = inputField.stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Now, the output is as expected. All "&"'s in the string are removed. However, when I try this with 2 characters, such as:

```
textToConvert = inputField.stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("HI", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

There is no dice, the two characters are never stripped from the string. It's very odd. Does anyone know why this would occur?

Edit: Here is the whole function (fixed version):

```
@IBAction func saySomethingPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var textToConvert = inputField.stringValue

        if (textToConvert == "Hello" || textToConvert == "hello" || textToConvert == "hey"){
                responseLabel.stringValue = "Well hello there!"
        }

        else {


        textToConvert = inputField.stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("HI", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

         textToConvert = textToConvert.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        responseLabel.stringValue = textToConvert

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, your code works exactly as expected for me in a playground

Comment: Can't replicate it either.

Comment: You're re assigning textToConvert with your second line to remove the & character. It should be textToConvert = textToConvert.stringbyReplacing....

Comment: @thefredelement Thank you very much! I just figured that mistake out right before seeing your post. If you add it as an answer I will gladly mark it as correct. Also, do you know about my second question in the OP? At the top?

Comment: I do not but am reading, I'd like to know this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness:

```
 textToConvert = inputField.stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("HI", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

     textToConvert = textToConvert.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

The textToConvert variable is being re-assinged.

Comment: Thank you so much @thefredelement!